# Show Child Rows as Columns

Tags: c#, join, datagridview

It's been a long time since I've done any serious work with relational database, and despite spending the last two hours searching the Internet and taking my best guesses, I just can't work out the necessary SQL Query expression.

I have three related tables:
Players - Contains a list of players
Coaches - Contains a list of coaches
Evaluations - Stores each coach's evaluation of each player as a number.

Each record in the third table therefore includes a field with the PlayerID, CoachID and the rating.

If I have 10 players and 3 coaches, then table 3 should have 30 records in it.

In order to populate these tables, I want to show the coaches names (pulled from the Coaches table) and display them as Columns in a **DataGridView** that has a Row for each player so that when you enter a value in a player's row under the coach's column, the value get's stored in Table 3 with the appropriate Player and Coach IDs.

I know I've done something like this year's ago in Microsoft Access, but I can't figure out how to build the Query in my **Dataset** so that I can bind it to the **DataGridView**.

I tried using the following SQL Query, but it doesn't let me edit the values in the Coach1 and Coach2 columns. I suspect that's because I have a one-many relationship between PlayerList and Evaluations and a one-many relationship between Coaches and Evaluations:

```
SELECT        PlayerList.Number, PlayerList.Name, PlayerList.Year, PlayerList.Height, PlayerList.Notes, PlayerList.AverageSkill, AVG(Evaluations.Skill) AS CoachSkill, 
                         'SELECT Skill FROM Evaluations 
WHERE (PlayerID = PlayerList.Number) AND (CoachID = 1)' AS Coach1, 
                         'SELECT Skill FROM Evaluations 
WHERE (PlayerID = PlayerList.Number) AND (CoachID = 2)' AS Coach2
FROM            Evaluations RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                         PlayerList ON Evaluations.PlayerID = PlayerList.Number
GROUP BY PlayerList.Number, PlayerList.Name, PlayerList.Year, PlayerList.Height, PlayerList.Notes, PlayerList.AverageSkill
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Application details: I'm working with C# in Visual Studio Express with a SQL-Server-CE database.

A little more reading leads me to believe that what I want is a PIVOT function which SQL-Server-CE doesn't support.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could create new DataRows and add columns dynamically. Then add all your created rows to a DataGridView.

Answer (score 0):

This something related to nested Grid, as hierarchical data

go through this link which in detailed explain how to use gridview/datgrids in scenarios like yours.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164077.aspx

hope this will resolve your issue.

Comment: Thank you for the link, I looked at that, but it doesn't really apply to the kind of relationship I have in my database. Take a look at the edit above, it may help explain my desired output. I might have structured my database incorrectly.

Comment: After reading the article again, I'm certain nested grids isn't what I need, what I need is a PIVOT which SQL-Server-CE doesn't support.